# multiple mobile htaccess redirects iphone/ipad

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mobile, web

ok, so i have a site **mywebsite.net**
i have 2 subdomains **mobi.mywebsite.net** and **ipad.mywebsite.net**

using the htaccess redirect it works fine for iphone/android
but i want to add ipad and redirect it to the ipad subdomain
here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} iPhone
RewriteRule .* http://mobi.Mywebsite.net/ [R]
```

i found this rewritecond for ipad (`RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iPad" [NC,OR]`)
but if i add it can i also add another rule for it to go to the ipad subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many rewrite rules as you want. The only thing you will have to watch for is the order you define them in, but in your case that wont be a concern. The following will redirect to your mobi site if the user agent includes the words "iphone" or "android". It will also redirect to your ipad site if the user agent includes the word "ipad".

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iPhone|android" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobi.Mywebsite.net/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "iPad" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ipad.Mywebsite.net/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't need the `[OR]` flag for your rewrite condition, but if you're getting redirect loops, you'll need to check against the hostname:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iphone|android) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mobi\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mobi.Mywebsite.net/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ipad [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^ipad\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://ipad.Mywebsite.net/ [L,R=301]
```

Note that these will redirect all requests to the root of `mobi` and `ipad`, the requested URI is not preserved. Meaning if you go to **mywebsite.net/some/path/** on an ipad, you'll get redirected to **ipad.mywebsite.net/**. If you want to make it so you get redirected to **ipad.mywebsite.net/some/path/**, you'll need to change the above 2 `RewriteRule` directives to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mobi.Mywebsite.net/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ipad.Mywebsite.net/$1 [L,R=301]
```